# $\nabla\int_{S_1(0)} f(|x|w)d\sigma(w) = \int_{S_1(0)} \nabla f(|x|w)d\sigma(w)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, divergence-operator

> Let $U=\{x:x\in \mathbb{R}^n, x\neq 0\}$ and $f\in C^2(U)$. Define,
>   for $x\in U$, $$f_{\#}(x) = \int_{S_1(0)} f(|x|w)d\sigma(w)$$ Show
>   that $\nabla(f_{\#}) = (\nabla f)_{\#}$
>
> Hint: use the divergence theorem and the formula for polar integration

I know that I must use the divergence theorem:

$$\int_{\Omega}div(\vec{X})(x) dx = \int_{\partial \Omega}\vec{X}(x)\cdot n(x) dx$$

But I don't know what it means by polar integration formula, since the polar integration technique is only for $\mathbb{R}^2$. I don't see what to do in $n$ dimensions.

I tried seeing the integral as

$$f_{\#}(x) = \int_{S_1(0)}f(|x|w)d\sigma(w) = \frac{1}{|x|^{n-1}}\int_{S_{|x|}(0)}f(w)d\sigma(w) $$

but then I'd have to take the laplacian of that, which is unpratical.

I tried to integrate both sides to end with a ball and try to see some divergence in order to apply the divergence theorem:

$$\int_0^1\int_{S_1(0)}|x|^ {n-1}f(|x|w)d\sigma(w) = \int_{B_1(0)}f(|x|w)d\sigma(w)$$

But I don't see how it helps.

I think the best way is to begin with $(\nabla)_{\#}$:

$$(\nabla f)_{\#}(x) = \int_{S_1(0)}\nabla f(|x|w)d\sigma w $$

I think that if I see the function as a vector field times the normal I can use the divergence theorem to transform this integral to an integral of a ball, but I think I cannot do that.